# dart pub add a git dependency by git-ssh

Tags: flutter, git, dart, pub.dev

If I add a dependency in this command

pub add my_package --git-url=git@git.test.com:tong/my_package.git --git-ref=0.0.1

It will tell me "The --git-url must be a valid url: Illegal scheme character."

[image]

Is it possible to add dependencies in this way? Or I have to use https.

I tried to escape the special characters in the address, but it didn't work.

Unable to resolve package "my_pacgage" with the given git parameters.
pub finished with exit code 65

Comment: ig you need to replace `my_pacgage` with your package name

Comment: my_pacgage is an example

Comment: Does it not support the use of SSH Git URL

Answer (score 0):

It perhaps is a bug with `pub` if it does not recognize SSH Git URLs added via the command-line, but you can manually edit your `pubspec.yaml` file to add such the dependency.  This is described by [the documentation for package dependencies](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages):

> Even if the package repo is private, if you can connect to the repo using SSH, then you can depend on the package by using the repo’s SSH URL:
>
> ```yaml
> dependencies:
>   kittens:
>     git: git@github.com:munificent/kittens.git
> ```